# Storing an NSURL return as an integer/numerical value rather than an NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsinteger

I am trying to return the contents of my `NSURL` request as an `integer/numerical` value rather than an `NSString`. I have had quite a bit of trouble with this. Does anyone know what the last line of code needs to be to do this? Thank you!

```
NSString *distanceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/distance.php?lat1=%@&lon1=%@&lat2=%@&lon2=%@",userLatitude, userLongitude, placeLatitude, placeLongitude];

NSData *distanceURLResult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:distanceURL]];

int distanceInFeet = distanceURLResult;
```

Comment: This is not in any way related to Xcode.

Comment: I tried to run this code and I get error 404: not found.It seems like I don't find the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
int distanceInFeet = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:distanceURLResult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] integerValue];
```

Check for the correct encoding of the returned data.

Comment: The format of the input is important. Make it part of the question!

Comment: I have tried to run that code, with a few modifications.I completely agree with demosten, he should have said what was the format.